# Why does `^[ ]{0,}` not work with linux grep?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

This is my sample text. `grep w`, `grep ^w` and `grep '^[ ]w'` are working just fine.

```
[user@linux ~]$ grep w text.txt
whitespace 0
 whitespace 1
  whitespace 2
[user@linux ~]$

[user@linux ~]$ grep ^w text.txt
whitespace 0
[user@linux ~]$
```

With 1 space

```
[user@linux ~]$ grep '^[ ]w' text.txt
 whitespace 1
[user@linux ~]$
```

With 2 space, but getting the same output

```
[user@linux ~]$ grep '^[  ]w' text.txt
 whitespace 1
[user@linux ~]$
```

According to https://regex101.com/, `^[ ]{0,}` is the right syntax to find whitespace at the start of a line. However, it doesn't work well with GNU grep on Linux. I'm getting the error `Invalid regular expression`:

```
[user@linux ~]$ grep ^[ ]{0,}w text.txt
grep: Invalid regular expression
[user@linux ~]$
```

And these do not return anything at all

```
[user@linux ~]$ grep '^[ ]{0}w' text.txt
[user@linux ~]$ grep '^[ ]{1}w' text.txt
[user@linux ~]$ grep '^[ ]{2}w' text.txt
[user@linux ~]$ grep '^[ ]{0,}w' text.txt
[user@linux ~]$
```

Question: Would it be possible to use `^[ ]{0,}` with GNU grep? If yes, what was wrong with my previous syntax?

Comment: `[  ]` is a character class and it matches anything it define not a pattern to match exact double spaces. so `[XXXXXX]` will always match single `X` character not string `XXXXXX`.

Comment: To match two spaces it might be easier to use `grep '^  w'` (two spaces after `^`).

Comment: The regex101 site does not know about POSX regular expression. See e.g. [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/119905)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are various issues here. First of all, the expression `^[ ]w` means: find the start of the line, then exactly one space, then a `w`. So it's actually working perfectly. If you want it to match one or more spaces, you need to add a qualifier to the `[ ]` character class:

```
  $ grep '^[  ]\+w' text.txt
 whitespace 1
  whitespace 2
```

The `+` means "one or more". The default flavor of regular expressions used by `grep` are called BRE (basic regular expressions) and in that regex flavor, the `+` needs to be escaped, hence the `\+` above<sup>*</sup>. Alternatively, you can use ERE (extended regular expressions) by passing the `-E` flag, or PCRE (Perl compatible regular expressions)  by passing the `-P` flag. With these regex flavors, you don't need to escape the `+` for it to act as a quantifier:

```
$ grep -P '^[  ]+w' text.txt
 whitespace 1
  whitespace 2
$ grep -E '^[  ]+w' text.txt
 whitespace 1
  whitespace 2
```

The next issue, and the more important one, is that you are not quoting the regular expression. Quoting is necessary to ensure that the regex is passed to `grep` *as is* and not first interpreted by the shell. However, since you are not quoting it, it is getting expanded by the shell before it is passed to `grep`. You can examine this by using the `set -x` option to have the shell print what it is doing:

```
$ set -x
$ grep ^[ ]{0,}w text.txt
+ grep '^[' ']0w' ']w' text.txt
grep: Invalid regular expression
```

First, because there is a space between the `^[` and the `]`, the shell is interpreting this as two separate arguments: `^[` and `]{0,}w`. But the `{}` are used in the shell for brace expansion. For example:

```
$ echo foo{a,b}
fooa foob
```

But when the second part of an expansion is empty, you get:

```
$ echo foo{a,}
fooa foo
```

So, the expansion `]{0,}w` becomes:

```
$ echo ]{0,}w
]0w ]w
```

And as a result, and as you can see in the output of the `set -x` above, these three arguments are what is actually passed to `grep`:

```
'^[' ']0w' ']w'
```

But if you do quote them, they will need to be escaped when using BRE, just like the `+` above:

```
$ grep '^[ ]\{2\}w' text.txt
  whitespace 2
```

One final note: the `[ ]` is exactly the same as , there's no point in using a character class for a single character.

Putting all this together, to match exactly one space at the beginning of the line, use:

```
$ grep '^ w' text.txt 
 whitespace 1
```

To match one or more, use:

```
$ grep '^ \+w' text.txt 
 whitespace 1
  whitespace 2
```

Or:

```
$ grep -E '^ +w' text.txt 
 whitespace 1
  whitespace 2
```

or

```
$ grep -P '^ +w' text.txt 
 whitespace 1
  whitespace 2
```

To match a specific number range (e.g. 0, 1 or 2 spaces):

```
$ grep '^ \{0,3\}w' text.txt 
whitespace 0
 whitespace 1
  whitespace 2
```

or

```
$ grep -P '^ {0,3}w' text.txt 
whitespace 0
 whitespace 1
  whitespace 2
```

or

```
$ grep -E '^ {0,3}w' text.txt 
whitespace 0
 whitespace 1
  whitespace 2
```

And to match a specific number, either set that number in the `{}` as shown above, or just repeat the character N times:

```
$ grep '^ \{2\}w' text.txt
  whitespace 2
$ grep '^ w' text.txt
 whitespace 1
$ grep '^  w' text.txt
  whitespace 2
```

And ***always quote your regular expressions!***

---

<sup>*</sup><sub>Actually, in POSIX BRE, the `+` has no special meaning, but the BRE implemented by GNU `grep` does recognize it if it is escaped.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

In BRE, in the greedy quantifiers expression `{0,}`, the braces need to be escaped to achieve the required regex match and always *quote* your regex string. Without the quotes, the shell tries to apply its own parsing grammar to the provided arguments and in most cases the arguments get word split making `grep` only see the `^[` part of the regex.

```
grep '^[ ]\{0,\}w' file
```

From [Regular Expression Reference: Quantifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) and choose GNU BRE

> `\{n,\}` where `n >= 0` Repeats the previous item at least `n` times. Greedy, so as many items as possible will be matched before trying permutations with less matches of the preceding item, up to the point where the preceding item is matched only n times.

As noted in the comments, use the `*` modifier which would be equivalent to using `\{0,\}`.

Comment: Using the `*` modifier would be equivalent to using `\{0,\}`.

Answer (score 0):

**Correct command :**

Use `grep -E '^[ ]{0,}' text.txt`

> -E, --extended-regexp Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular
>   expression (ERE, see below).

**Reason why its not working:**

Not using single quotes around regex, bash will open it and your command will become

`grep '^['   ]   ]0 text.txt` which translates to grep with regex `'^['` on files `]` , `]0` and `text.txt`

`^[` is wrong as `[` is special charater which requires closing character `]` too

**Why -E option:**

{m,n} is an extended regular expression, and to use it grep requires -E option